# Module Import Inconsistency IDLE vs command line

Tags: python, numpy, biopython

I have python 3.3 setup on a Windows 7 machine. I am able to import Bio from IDLE, but not numpy or skimage. I get the following error:

```
import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 168, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

sys.path yeilds:

```
['', 'C:\\Python33\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\Python33\\python33.zip', 'C:\\Python33\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python33\\lib', 'C:\\Python33', 'C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages']
```

When I use the python interpreter directly, or run a file from the desktop via command line, I am able to import numpy, but not skimage or Bio. The error simply states an inability to find the module. This sys.path yields:

```
['/cygdrive/c/Users/michael.alonge/Desktop', '/usr/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-cygwin', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info']
```

When I look to adjust my system variable, I find the following variable under User variables:

```
Variable Name: PATH
Value: C:\Python33\Lib;C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python33\Lib\idlelib;C:\Python33.zip;C:\Python33\DLLs;C:\Python33\Lib;C:\Python33
```

It seems as if there is an inconsistency with my path depending on where I launch the file from. For some reason, the file launched from the Desktop is trying to access python 2.7. I have Bio, numpy, and skimage downloaded and installed in C:Python33/Lib/site-packages. I'd like to be able to access all modules from IDLE or from files themselves.

Thank you

Comment: how did you install numpy?

Comment: I downloaded numpy‑MKL‑1.9.0.win‑amd64‑py3.3.exe from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Comment: Your python seems to be 32 bit, so you have an architecture mismatch

Comment: I installed the 32 bit version of numpy, and now I can access it from IDLE and from the desktop file, but Biopython is not cooperating. I definitely installed the 32 bit version from http://biopython.org/wiki/Download and I can access via IDLE but not the desktop file.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: $ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from Bio import Seq
ImportError: No module named Bio

Comment: that is not a the same error, that is not having the module installed or having it installed somewhere python cannot find it.

Comment: Exactly, but when I launch from IDLE it can import it with no problem. And the 32 bit file is successfully installed in the same directory as the numpy packages at C:/Python33/Lib/site-packages. Why would I not be able to import from a file located in the Desktop, but I am able to from IDLE.

Comment: are you sure `python test.py ` refers to python3 and not python 2, have you tried using something like `python3 test.py` or maybe `python33` I don't use windows?

Comment: Ok it worked fine when I pointed directly to the path like this: /cygdrive/c/Python33/python test.py. I guess I have to figure out how to make the default python command point to python 3. If you're not a windows user I suppose you don't know how to do this, but I know in mac you would edit the .bash_profile. Thank you

Comment: did using `python3` or `python33` not work?

Comment: No those didnt work. The shell didnt recognize python33 as a command and I got the same "not module named Bio" error when I used python3

Comment: you have set the environment variable yes?what happens if you add `#! python3` to the top of your script? Might be worth your while looking here https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html

Comment: I have PATH:C:\Python33\Lib;C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python33\Lib\idlelib;C:\Python33.zip;C:\Python33\DLLs;C:\Python33\Lib;C:\Python33 and PYTHONPATH:C:\Python33\Lib;C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python33\Lib\idlelib;C:\Python33.zip;C:\Python33\DLLs;C:\Python33\Lib;C:\Python33

Comment: have a look at the link I posted, you should get what you need from that

Comment: the #! python3 did not work either. I'll take a look at the link. Thanks for all of your help.